# Where should I go from here? (Cocos2D+UIKit)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, where-clause

Currently I have this code in my UIViewController:

```
//Cocos2D methods
-(id) init {
    if((self=[super init]))
    {
        CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
        CCLayer *layer = [CCLayer node];
        [scene addChild:layer];
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:scene];
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDisplayFPS:NO];
        [self performSelector:@selector(cocosgameLoop:) withObject:nil afterDelay:1/60.0f];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)cocosgameLoop:(ccTime)dT {
    //Check for collisions here and add gravity, etc....
}
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] end];
}
//
```

My view controller is somewhat Objective-C code, but I want to add Cocos2D to the UIView. I think the code above is initializing it, but I am not sure. Also should the CCScene have its own class dedicated to everything that goes on in the scene? if so how would I do that?
I know these are a lot of questions, but my game is very similar to Doodle Jump and I need to know where to go from the current state I am in.
Does anyone have any ideas/tips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

performSelector will call the cocosgameLoop only once. You will want to call CCDirector startAnimation, and then schedule updates in your cocos2d nodes.

My [Learn Cocos2D book](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/store/book-learn-cocos2d/) (2nd Edition) explains how to add and setup Cocos2D in a UIKit view (regular iPhone) app.